# iterated loop spaces and configuration spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, operads

In the lecture notes by J.P. May, The geometry of iterated loop spaces, Chapter 5, formula (1), (2) and (10), a map 
$$
\phi: Hom_T(X,\Omega Y)\to Hom_T(SX,Y)
$$
is defined. And a map
$$
\eta_n=\phi^{-n}(1_{S^nX}):X\to \Omega^n S^nX.
$$

Question: I do not quite understand what does $\eta_n$ mean? What means $\phi^{-n}(1_{S^nX})$?

Comment: [Identical question on MO.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207915/iterated-loop-spaces-and-configuration-spaces) Please, stop doing that. This is at least the second time that I answer one of your questions on math.SE only to discover you had asked it at the same time on MO, and had already gotten an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ is the map that appears in the [standard adjunction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443259/loop-space-suspension-adjunction) between loop spaces and suspension: the suspension functor $S$ is the left adjoint of the loop space functor $\Omega$. This is a very slight abuse of notation, as the map $\phi$ depends on the spacse $X$ and $Y$, so it could actually be called
$$\phi_{X,Y} : \hom_T(X, \Omega Y) \to \hom_T(SX, Y)$$
Being part of an adjunction, $\phi$ is a bijection, so it makes sense to talk about its inverse.

The map $1_{S^n X}$ is the identity of the iterated $n$th suspension of the space $X$: $S^n X = S(S(\dots S(X) \dots))$. We have $1_{S^n X} \in \hom_T(S^n X, S^n X)$; we can apply the inverse of the adjunction map to get $\phi_{S^{n-1}X, S^n X}^{-1}(1_{S^n}) \in \hom_T(S^{n-1} X, \Omega S^n X)$. You can continue to apply the adjunction to eventually get a map in $\hom_T(X, \Omega^n S^n X)$; this is the map that May denotes $\phi^{-n}(1_{S^n})$. Again, it's a slight abuse of notation, as the map $\phi$ is not the same at each step (first it's $\phi_{S^{n-1}X, S^n X}$, then $\phi_{S^{n-2}X, \Omega S^n X}$, etc.) but it's not really a big deal.

You can also view it this way: since $S$ is left adjoint to $\Omega$, $S^n$ is left adjoint to $\Omega^n$ (essentially what I just did), and $\eta_n$ is the unit of this adjunction at $X$.